# PDFsharp: is it possible to export a PdfDocument to MDDDL?

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using PDFsharp to work with PDF documents; on the same solution I use MigraDoc to create invoice PDFs.  I was wondering if I could open an existing PDF using PdfDocument and extract the information to create a MDDDL file.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: No, you cannot.

The long answer: With a lot of own code you can get it going, but not out of the box.